# exctract binary expression from string

Tags: python

I have a file in which for what ever case words are saved in python style binary representation:

```py
file = ["b'first'", "b'second'"]
```

Is it possible to extract this and save the bit representation to a variable (to perform decoding) without regexing the values between the single quotes and then encode and decode the string?

Comment: It's already in a variable, what do you mean by "save it to a variable"?

Comment: You can use `ast.literal_eval()` to decode the strings to byte strings.

Comment: the save to variable was a bit misleading, I want the byte representation because I need to decode it to utf-8. ast sounds like a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yep

```
>>> file = ["b'first'", "b'second'"]
>>> for it in file:
...  print(ast.literal_eval(it))
...
b'first'
b'second'
```

also u can apply `map` function

```
import ast
file = ["b'first'", "b'second'"]

file_2=map(ast.literal_eval,file)
#<map object at 0x0000000002E8EFA0>

file_3=list(file_2)
#[b'first', b'second']
```

Comment: isn't eval an security issue, espacially in this case because reading from a simple file?

Comment: Use `ast.literal_eval()`, not `eval()`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use slicing:

```
file = ["b'first'", "b'second'"]
bytestrings = [bytes(x[2:-1], 'ascii') for x in file]
```

Comment: This was also a approach I had in mind, but I delayed this approach for the obvious reason of hard coded slicing. It might work for my problem in 99.9% of the cases, but I always would have this problem in mind.